# Como passar argumentos em um procedimento armazenado no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Como eu faço pra passar esses argumentos dentro da CALL? Quando eu coloco 9 valores aleatórios dentro de LET sql("..."), ele executa, mas passando dessa maneira retorna este erro. Segui esse tutorial -> https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/call-stored-procedures/
Porém não ensina como passar mais de um argumento, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço. (Obs.: Sou iniciante)

Código:

```js
router.post('/pedido_final', function(req, res){

  let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3309,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'XXXXX',
    database: 'XXXXX'
  });

  let sql = `CALL recebePedido(?)`

  let dados = [req.body[0].nMesa, req.body[0].idProd, req.body[0].Quantidade,
  req.body[0].codFun, req.body[0].p, req.body[0].sabores, req.body[0].nomeCli, req.body[0].nmrCelCli, 
  req.body[0].Obs]

  connection.query(sql, dados, (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.error(error.message);
    }
    console.log(results[0]);
  });
  
  connection.end(); });
```

Recebo o seguinte erro desta maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta alterar essa linha:

let sql = `CALL recebePedido(?)` para let sql = `CALL recebePedido(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)` pois ele esta reclamando que espera nove argumentos e voce está passando somente 1.

Espero ter ajudado.